# How can I recover my Trello account if I've lost my Google account too?

Tags: trello, account-recovery

I deleted my Google account that is associated with Trello and I can't recover my Trello account. I can't recover my Google account because I deleted it long time ago.

There is a chance to recover my Trello account?

I see that the only way to recover a lost password is sending an email linked to the account. This not acceptable because Trello company doesn't belong to Google company, so there should be another way to recover my Trello account.

Answer (score 3):

I would think about how I could convince someone that it really *is my account* and email Fog Creek, the company behind Trello, at customer-service@fogcreek.com. Good luck!

Comment: We would prefer an email at support@trello.com, so it gets routed to the right place.